# recover data from a previously RAID 1 drive?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

Normally it's a drive that fails, but in this case it was my motherboard (I think).   System is completely dead.   It was a Dell XPS420 with a Intel ICH7R Matrix RAID controller on the motherboard.

Now I am left with the drives (WD Black 1TB), which I'm pretty desperate to recover the data from.   I put one into a SATA external case and plugged it into another system, and it works but shows the entire drive as "Unallocated."

I'm not normally a hardware guy - is there a utility or something I can use to read this drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky, the RAID configuration is not the problem. RAID 1 is mirroring so each single HDD should hold all your data.
I would
- not use/connect/touch the other HDD until absolutely necessary
- get hold of a standard PC with Intel chipset and connect the other drive internally. Hopefully, the Intel RST driver is installed. I was not aware that it put administrative data onto the volume but that's how it looks like.
- using the same OS (probably Windows), copy all data over to an external USB drive (which you use anyway for backup, right?)
- I would NOT trust any USB-to-SATA controller built-in in any external case to be able to read the metadata on a RAID drive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that as soon as I can get ahold of another Intel PC!   And yes, by pure chance, I had a backup only a couple days old (whew!)